# JavaFx prevent client to launch application multiple times

Tags: java, javafx, singleton, javafx-11

I want to prevent client to launch the application multiple times. I thought of implementing Singleton Pattern.

```
public class MyClass extends Application {

private static MyClass app = null;

private MyClass (){
    super();   
}

public static MyClass getInstance(){
    if(app == null){
    app = new MyClass();
    }
    return app; 
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLLogin.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setOpacity(0.95);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

However, when I run the app, an error shows up:

```
 Exception in Application constructor
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class  authentification.MyClass
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: authentification.MyClass.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$7(LauncherImpl.java:818)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
... 1 more
Exception running application authentification.MyClass
```

Can someone explain me why? and is it the idea of the Singleton is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051127/javafx-single-instance-application) helps you

Answer (score 5):

The lifecycle of a JavaFX application is controlled by the `Application` class. The static `Application.launch(...)` method starts the application; it does so by *creating an instance of the `Application` class* (by default the class from which `launch()` is called), *calling its no-argument constructor*. Since your singleton approach makes the no-argument constructor private, the startup process is no longer able to instantiate your `Application` class, and you get the exception shown.

However, even without this issue, making your application class a singleton would not achieve what you want. The singleton pattern you use here merely ensures that only one instance of the class can exist *within any Java Virtual Machine*. If the user launches the application a second time, they create a second JVM, which can have its own instance of your singleton.

To ensure only one application can run at a time, you need some OS-level mechanism of locking the application launch. One approach is to start listening on a specific port at startup and closing that connection at shutdown. Since only one application may listen on a given port, this achieves the desired effect. See [JavaFX Single Instance Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051127/javafx-single-instance-application) for an example.